# Mathematica 9: how to solve a maximization?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maximization

How can I maximize the following equation in respect to `$\tau$` in Mathematica 9:

```
$$max_\tau \sqrt{(1 - \tau)y^i} + \sqrt{\tau y}$$
```

I want to find something like

```
$$\tau^i = \frac{y}{y^i + y}$$
```

Comment: Please have a look at `Maximize`.

Answer (score 0):

Let x = Τ then f(x, y) = sqrt((1-x)*y^c) + sqrt(xy)

I'll assume that c is a constant, so there are only two independent variables here.

So take the first partial derivative w.r.t. x and set that equal to zero.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d/dx%20%28sqrt%28%281-x%29%2ay%5Ec%29%20%20%2b%20sqrt%28x%2ay%29%29) can help you with that.